# Spring annotations don't work after adding Spring Security libraries (Maven)

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, dependencies

I added to my Spring MVC application (3.2.5) Spring Security libraries (version 3.1.4) into my pom.xml to work with Spring Security (see added dependencies later). But now don't work annotations I use in my Configuration classes.

**What am I doing wrong?**

This is an Eclipse error:

[image]

Error messages:

[image]

Spring dependencies in pom.xml (annotations work with it):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring Security dependencies in pom.xml (annotations don't work with it):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: are you using the maven eclipse plugin?

Comment: @reagten - yes, I do.

Answer (score 3):

since spring-security-core 3.1.4.RELEASE has a dependency on spring-context 3.0.7.RELEASE you'll need to explicitly add a dependency for spring-context 3.2.5.RELEASE to force maven to use the latest version.

At least .ComponentScan was added in 3.1 only.

EDIT:
as stated by **M. Deinum**, use a `<dependencyManagement>` block where you define all your dependency versions. thus you can leave out any `<version>` tags in your "main" `<dependencies>` block.

Comment: Correct. In general I use a `<dependencyManagement />` block in maven to force versions of a particular framework.

Comment: Well, I have solved the dependencies problem from my original question, but now I need to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and this class was added in Spring Security 3.2.0.RC. Is it solvable?